# Почему переменная обладает такой областью видимости?

Tags: javascript

Доброго ночи!

При разборе, казалось бы легкого скрипта, обнаружил для себя не совсем понятный момент.

`Javascript`:

```
var planetList = new Array();
  planetList[0] = 'Меркурий';
  planetList[1] = 'Венера';
  planetList[2] = 'Земля';
  planetList[3] = 'Марс';

var wayToSun = new Array();
  wayToSun[0] = '52 млн.км';
  wayToSun[1] = '108 млн.км';
  wayToSun[2] = '149 млн.км';
  wayToSun[3] = '228 млн.км';

var planetDiameter = new Array();
  planetDiameter[0] = '4 880 км';
  planetDiameter[1] = '12 100 км';
  planetDiameter[2] = '12 750 км';
  planetDiameter[3] = '6 800 км';

function doCount(){
   var userText = document.getElementById('planetName').value;
   for( var i = 0; i < planetList.length; i++) {
     if(planetList[i] == userText){
        break;
     }
   }
document.write('<p class="hightlight">'+planetList[i]+'</p>');
document.write('<p class="hightlight">Расстояние до солнца: '+wayToSun[i]+'</p>');
document.write('<p class="hightlight">Диаметр планеты: '+planetDiameter[i]+'</p>');
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<label for="planetName">Введите название планеты:</label>
<input type="text" id="planetName" name="planetName" />
<input type="button" id="counter" value="Рассчитать" onclick="doCount()"/>
```

Как я и говорил всё до банальности просто, мат.часть так скажем. Но вот ситуацию почему  скрипт перестаёт "работать", когда переменная `userText` объявляется вне тела функции (если я всё правильно понимаю, в таком случае она является глобальной), я никак не могу осилить.

Comment: А вне тела функции она существует? Не создается ли в каком-нибудь замыкании? Попробуйте явно присваивать ее объекту `window`:

    window.userText = document.getElementById('planetName').value;
    var foo = window.userText;

Comment: В том и дело. если вне тела функции объявлять, то её значение равно `null`. в этом и есть непонятный момент. по моей идее она должна быть глобальной и быть доступной функции.

Comment: Хм, `null` или все же `undefined`? Создайте [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), посмотрим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение `input` нам нужно после нажатия на кнопку, верно? Ее не нужно получать *заранее*, в этом нет смысла. Дело даже не в DOM, как я написал сперва (удалять ту часть ответа не буду, вдруг пригодится).

---

Сравните два фиддла: [определение переменной внутри функции](http://jsfiddle.net/SX6hH/6/) и [снаружи](http://jsfiddle.net/SX6hH/7/). (Для обработки события `onclick` была заюзана jQuery из-за траблов с iframeами, но на конечный результат это никак не влияет).

В первом варианте мы делаем выборку нужного элемента после клика на клавишу, когда дерево DOM уже построено (и этот элемент присутствует в документе).

Во втором - мы выбираем элемент сразу же, не смотря на то, что, возможно, он еще не присутствует в DOM, что и дает нам значение `undefined`.

То есть - необходимо дождаться, когда нужный элемент будет доступен в DOM, после этого только делать выборку. Варианты:

- дождаться события `document.ready` (предпочтительный)
- перенести JS в конец страницы (ну или хотя бы вставить его **после** объявления нужного html-элемента

Comment: нет-нет-нет, так пойдёт) Первая часть Вашего ответа - это и есть тескстовая часть моего вопроса) я именно так и "игрался" с расположением переменной `userText` (объявлял её вне тела функции и в нём), так что fiddle Ваши показали мне то, что я уже видел). Но Вы мне помогли разобраться с этой проблемой. за это плюсую!)

Comment: Я не понимаю... А была ли проблема?

Comment: была!)был не понятен механизм, но с Вами я достаточно быстро разобрался в происходящем)спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-scriptum** Данный ответ пишу, дабы поведать, что я понял и попытаться донести это до человека, которого будет интересовать нечто подобное.

Дело тут не в области видимости (в этом я был абсолютно не прав), а в событиях!на самом деле для инициализации переменной `userText` должно произойти какое-либо событие. Добавим простую функцию, которая будет "забирать" значение поля до нажатия кнопки:

`Javascript`

```
function getText(){
   userText = document.getElementById('planetName').value;
}
```

Вот и всё. теперь можно объявлять переменную до тела всех функций, в которых она используется, размещать сам скрипт в любой части страницы ([[@neoascetic](/users/4022/neoascetic)](/users/4022/neoascetic) так и писал).

А проблема, указанная мной в вопросе, происходила не потому что элемент не существовал в дереве `DOM` (точнее, не только из-за этого, позднее поясню). Вот поэтому изначально в значение переменной `userText` и попадало значение `undefined`, а так как изменение переменной никак не отслеживалось, то и возникала эта проблема (но это я опять возвращаюсь в события). Цикл должен вернуть значение `i` для определения совпадения введённого пользователем строки с элементами массива, совпадения нет - получаем `i==undefined`. Вот в чём суть.

Но окончание построения дерева `DOM` играет всё-таки свою роль. Если изначально значение атрибуту `value` текстового поля, строка: (вне тела функции `doCount()`)

```
var userText = document.getElementById('planetName').value;
```

тоже будет присваивать значение `null` переменной. Но если написать следующее **до** указанной выше функции:

```
var userText;
function getValue(){
    userText = document.getElementById('planetName').value;
}
```

и вызвать эту функцию после создания текстового поля (разместить тег `<script>` с вызовом функции `getValue()` после соответствующего `input`, то всё опять-таки будет работать. Получаем глобальную переменную, которая инициализируется значением, заданным по умолчанию и которая потом передаётся в цикл для поиска совпадений.

Вот такая, на первый взгляд, простая задачка из матчасти, но с подводными камнями. 
Я надеюсь, у меня получилось описать суть проблемы достаточно подробно и наглядно.

Comment: Не `null`, а `undefined`.

Comment: Да, Вы вполне правы, ведь элемент на момент инициализации ещё не существует.

Comment: Но лучше юзать jQuery, `document.ready` и получать удовольствие от программирования

Comment: да, я знаю. цель выучить именно `javascript`.